# Como substituir cada ocorrência do match de uma expressão regular por um valor diferente?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Tenho um texto (código html) com várias imagens no formato padrão HTML:

`<img src="X" atributos />`

Preciso que o valor do atributo *src* seja substituído pelo identificador **CID:#** onde **#** é um valor único que identifica cada imagem (veja no código abaixo). Ou seja, cada imagem terá um valor diferente dentro desse atributo.

Abaixo o código que já fiz até o momento, ele já faz o match das imagens corretamente. Mas como fazer essa substituição?

Outra informação importante é que eu preciso ter no código a informação de qual identificador único substituiu qual valor (url da imagem) do atributo *src*. Por exemplo, preciso ter uma forma de saber que o identificador 354 substituiu o valor "img/xxx.jpg".

```
preg_match_all('/<img src=[",\']([^>,^\',^"]*)[",\']([^>]*)/', $html, $matches);

$url_imagem = array();
$atributos_imagem = array();
$cid = array();
$contador = 0;

foreach ($matches[1] as $i => $img){

    $url_imagem[$contador] = $matches[2][$i];
    $atributos_imagem[$contador] = $matches[3][$i];

    //Como substituir o conteudo do atributo SRC com o valor da variável $cid abaixo?
    $cid[$contador] = "CID:".date('YmdHms').'.'.time();

    $contador++;   
}
```

Comment: Os `src`s das imagens são diferentes?

Comment: Não tenho controle sobre o conteúdo dos srcs. Então podem ser iguais ou diferentes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro esse `$contador = 0;` é desnecessário no `foreach`, já que a variável `$i` já retorna os índices iniciando do `0`, ou seja, onde você usa `$contador` pode substituir por `$i`.

Outro problema é no valor que você está pegando usando *data* e *horas*:

```
$cid[$i] = "CID:".date('YmdHms').'.'.time();
```

Desta forma todos os valores de `$cid[$i]` terão o mesmo valor porque o laço irá correr de forma a não diferenciar o tempo do sistema. Isso significa que a cada volta no laço, o tempo será o mesmo e se for substituir os `src`s das imagens, todas ficarão com o mesmo valor.

Para ter certeza de que cada valor será diferente, você pode acrescentar um outro valor único, o próprio `$i`:

```
                                     concatenar o $i
                                            ↓
$cid[$i] = "CID:".date('YmdHms').'.'.time().$i;
```

E finalmente, para fazer a substituição, você pode usar o `preg_replace` substituindo a primeira ocorrência:

```
$html = preg_replace('/'.$img.'/', $cid[$i], $html, 1);
```

Criei também uma array `$identificador = array();` para ir armazenando as `src`s substituídas para que você pode saber quais foram e em qual sequência.

**Exemplo:**

Imagens iniciais:

```
$html = '<img src="link1" atributos />
<img src="link2" atributos />
<img src="link1" atributos />';
```

Note que a 3ª imagem possui o mesmo `src` da 1ª. Após a substituição, ficará algo assim:

```
                                                ↓
$html = '<img src="CID:20180627170651.15301318110" atributos />
<img src="CID:20180627170651.15301318111" atributos />
<img src="CID:20180627170651.15301318112" atributos />';
                                       ↑
```

Veja nas setas que o `$i` torna um valor diferente do outro.

O código ficaria assim:

```
preg_match_all('/<img src=[",\']([^>,^\',^"]*)[",\']([^>]*)/', $html, $matches);

$url_imagem = array();
$atributos_imagem = array();
$cid = array();
$identificador = array();

foreach ($matches[1] as $i => $img){

    $url_imagem[$i] = $matches[1][$i];
    $atributos_imagem[$i] = $matches[2][$i];

    //Como substituir o conteudo do atributo SRC com a variável $cid abaixo?
    $cid[$i] = "CID:".date('YmdHms').'.'.time().$i;
    $tag_img = str_replace("/", "\/", $img);    
    $html = preg_replace('/'.$tag_img.'/', $cid[$i], $html, 1);
    $identificador[$i] = $img;

}
```

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta! O problema é que não posso considerar que os srcs necessariamente serão diferentes.

Comment: Uma ideia seria tentar aproveitar o $i para substiuir a $i-ésima ocorrência, substituindo exatamente o src atual, porém não consegui fazer.

Comment: Entendi... Vou reanalisar aqui...

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. O correto seria usar `preg_replace` substituindo a primeira ocorrência. Assim vai substituindo na sequência, sem importar se há imagens com o mesmo src.

Comment: Excelente resposta! Deu certo, obrigada!